# How to encode chars in 2-bits? in java

Tags: java, bit, bit-shift

DNA molecules are denoted by one of four values: A, C, G, or T. I need to convert a string of characters from A, C, G, and T to an array of bytes, encoding each of the characters
with two bits.A with bits 00, C with bits 01, G with 10, and T with 11.  I don't understand how to convert characters to 2 bits. I was trying to shift and mask, but got wrong result.
At the very beginning, I check if there are characters in the line. Then i convert each character into a bit value and insert it into an array. When i insert ACGT, in the output i got 0 1 3 2. And here I have a problem, because I don’t understand how to convert the value to 2 bits.

```
Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = text.nextLine();

if (str.contains("A") && str.contains("C") && str.contains("G") && str.contains("T")){
  System.out.println("");
}
else
{
  System.out.println("wrong command format");
} 

byte mas[] = str.getBytes();
System.out.println("String in byte array : " + Arrays.toString(mas));

for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++){
  byte mask = 3;
  byte number = mas[i];
  byte result = (byte)((number >> 1) & mask); 
  System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not a Java expert but wouldn't a simple foreach loop in combination of a string replace function do exactly what you'd want? I'm assuming you be doing further processing after you got an array with 2-bit values.

Comment: show us some code. We might be able to find the issue with it.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make some kind of attempt and show sample input and expected output.

Comment: "I was trying to shift and mask, but got wrong result."—If you post that code and explain the problem, someone might tell you why it's going wrong.

Comment: You could store in groups of 8 in a char. Storing would be easy:dnaEncoded=dna1 + 16*dna2 + 64*dna3 where the variables dna are the letters encoded as 00,01,10 and 11.Decoding would be a bit more complicated but not too bad.

Comment: Just saying: the idiomatic solution in Java: to define an Enum, and then EnumSets for example. Java is a higher level OO language, if you want to do low level bit manipulation, then why use Java, instead of C?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the requirements, in particular your phrase "to an array of bytes, encoding each of the characters with two bits". A byte has 8 bits; do you therefore want to encode 4 characters into a byte? Or just one character into each byte?

Comment: either but 4 characters per char ou int(same capacity) or another solution use a 2 dimensiol array of Boolean[x][2] where x is the number of characters to store. Each character is therefore stored in an array of 2 Booleans. I'm working on a script for the latter option. I don't know how efficient this is in terms of memory and performance.

Comment: Do you realise that a `boolean` is a primitive type that takes up 8 bits? A byte is the smallest addressable storage type. And a `Boolean` array is an array of Objects (boxed type) each of which takes up 16 bytes and points to a 1-byte boolean value. Note the significant difference between `boolean` and `Boolean`.

Comment: Thank you. I had my doubts about the solution but I thought I'd code it for practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to save the bits in a byte. The following example might give some ideas.

```java
public class Main
{
    private static final int A = 0x00; // b00
    private static final int C = 0x01; // b01
    private static final int G = 0x02; // b10
    private static final int T = 0x03; // b11
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        byte store = 0;
        store = setByte(store, 0, A);
        store = setByte(store, 1, C);
        store = setByte(store, 2, G);
        store = setByte(store, 3, T);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(store));
        //11111111111111111111111111100100
        System.out.println(getByte(store, 0)); //0
        System.out.println(getByte(store, 1)); //1
        System.out.println(getByte(store, 2)); //2
        System.out.println(getByte(store, 3)); //3
    }
    
    //Behavior :: Store "value" into "store".
    //Reminder :: Valid index 0 - 3. Valid value 0 - 3.
    private static byte setByte(byte store, int index, int value)
    {   
        store = (byte)(store & ~(0x3 << (2 * index)));
        return store |= (value & 0x3) << (2 * index);
    }

    private static byte getByte(byte store, int index)
    {
        return (byte)((store >> (2 * index)) & 0x3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Logical OR in `return store |= (value & 0x3) << (2 * index);` doesn't work if the bits at the index already contain 1's. For example:
store `01` at index 3:
`1010 0010 | 0001 0000` = `0011 0000`, which isn't what it should be, namely `1001 0010`. Hence, you first have to clear the bits at the index, as I did in my example.

Comment: My mistake, the wrong example OR should be `1010 0010 | 0001 0000` = `1011 0010`.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. Edited my code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it may help you.

```java
byte test = 69;
byte insert = 0b01;
byte index = 2;
final byte ones = 0b00000011;
//Clear out the data at specified index
test = (byte) (test & ~(ones << index));
//Insert data
test |= (byte) (insert << index);
```

It works as follows:

1. Clear the 2 bits at the index in the byte (using bitwise AND).
2. Insert the 2 data bits at the index in the byte using bitwise OR).

Answer (score 0):

You can "convert" the chars ACGT to 0, 1, 2, 3 using bit arithmetic.

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)(bytes[i] >> 1 & 3 ^ bytes[i] >> 2 & 1);
}
```

---

I suspect your initial check should be:

```
if (!str.matches("[ACGT]+") {
    System.out.println("wrong command format");
    return;
}
```