# The binary-DNA encoding

Tags: java

There is a problem, it is necessary to encode the DNA code in both directions. I have found the half of solution: [How to encode chars in 2-bits? in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71203792/how-to-encode-chars-in-2-bits-in-java?noredirect=1#comment125870543_71203792)
But it doesn`t works for me. 4 symbols: A - 00 bits, C - 01 bits, G - 10 bits, T - 11 bits.
it turned out to encode, but how to display the result in print, while separating the characters. I need to encode the output hex notation

My code:

```
public static String compileDnk(String input) {
        if(input.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("wrong command format");
            return "";
        }
 
        input = input.toUpperCase();
 
        if (!input.matches("[ACGT]+")) {
            System.out.println("wrong command format");
            return "";
        }
 
 
        byte store = 0;
        for (char subString : input.toCharArray()) {
            store = setByte(store, getByChar(subString), getByChar2(subString));
        }
 
        //But this output is: 11111111111111111111111111100000
        return Integer.toBinaryString(store);
    }
 
private static byte setByte(byte store, int index, int value) {
        store = (byte)(store & ~(0x3 << (2 * index)));
        return (byte) (store | (value & 0x3) << (2 * index));
}
```

Comment: what should the actual output look like ?

Comment: For the input string - CGATAAG
The output should be 7 63 8
where 7 - symbols count

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What does "But it doesn`t works for me" mean? In what way is it not working?

Comment: I don't know how to draw the output that is required. Since it turned out to translate everything into bits, but I don’t know how to output

Comment: See [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Do not add more information in comments, edit the question please.

Answer (score 1):

This is as much as I can do. Everything is pretty straightforward.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
        String dna = "CGATAAG";
        System.out.println(encode(dna)); //7 63 08
        System.out.println(decode("7 63 8")); //CGATAAG
        System.out.println(decode("7 63 08")); //CGATAAG
        
}
    
public static String encode(String dna)
{
        final int size = dna.length();
        dna = dna.replace("A","0").replace("C","1").replace("G","2").replace("T","3");
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)Math.ceil(size / 4D)];
        for(int i=0, count=0, index=0; i<size; ++i, ++count) {
            final int value = dna.charAt(i) - '0';
            switch(count) {
                case  0: bytes[index] |= (value & 3) << 6; break;
                case  1: bytes[index] |= (value & 3) << 4; break;
                case  2: bytes[index] |= (value & 3) << 2; break;
                default: bytes[index] |= value & 3; break;
            }
            if(count == 3) { count = -1; ++index; }
        }
        return String.format("%d %s", size, toHexString(bytes, 0, bytes.length, false, ' '));
}
    
private static final char[] hex = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
private static final char[] HEX = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes, int startIndex, int quantity, boolean lowercase, char delimiter)
{
        int bound = bytes.length;
        final char[] hexDigit = lowercase ? hex : HEX;
        final boolean hasDelimiter = delimiter == '\r' ? false : true;
        final char[] hex = hasDelimiter ? new char[quantity * 3] : new char[quantity << 1];
        final int value;
        bound = startIndex + quantity;
        for(int i=0; startIndex != bound; startIndex++) {
            value = bytes[startIndex] & 0xFF;
            hex[i++] = hexDigit[value >> 4];
            hex[i++] = hexDigit[value & 0x0F];
            if(hasDelimiter) hex[i++] = delimiter;
        }
        return hasDelimiter ? new String(hex, 0, (quantity * 3) - 1) :  new String(hex, 0, quantity << 1);
}

public static String decode(String encodedDna)
{
        final char[] dna = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };
        final String[] fields = encodedDna.split(" ");
        final int size = Integer.parseInt(fields[0], 10);
        final char[] chars = new char[size];
        int index = 0, count = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<fields.length; ++i) {
            final int value = Integer.parseInt(fields[i], 16);
            for(int ii=0; ii<4 && count<size; ++ii, ++count) {
                switch(ii) {
                    case  0: chars[index++] = dna[(value & 0xC0) >> 6]; break;
                    case  1: chars[index++] = dna[(value & 0x30) >> 4]; break;
                    case  2: chars[index++] = dna[(value & 0x0C) >> 2]; break;
                    default: chars[index++] = dna[value & 0x03]; break;
                }
            }
        }
        return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: Very nice! It worked, thanks. One question remains, how to implement the reverse process, from a string like 7 63 8 to get a DNA code

Comment: Oh great, so you do the whole homework for the OP, even without any further explanations.

Comment: You should post that as a new question. And please show some effort next time. I've included to decode that thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.

**Setup**

First, set up some maps to map between encoded and non-encoded values. The map types for encoding and decoding are different to facilitate each method in which they are used.

```
static Map<Character, Byte> dnaToCode =
        Map.of('A', (byte) 0, 'G', (byte) 2, 'C', (byte) 1, 'T', (byte) 3);
static Map<Integer, String> codeToDna =
        Map.of(0, "A", 2, "G", 1, "C", 3, "T");
```

**Encoding**

The general idea is to iterate over the `dna` strand, map the nucleotide to its 2 bit equivalent, converting every pair to a hex digit and return the string.

- define a string for converstion to hex
- define a few types for storage and processing
- Since every two nucleotides equate to one hex digit, increment the loop by two.
- assign the first bit pair to a byte variable
- shift left two bits for the next encoding.
- check to see if the end has been reached (and odd strand length). If so, skip it.
- else store next value and append a hex digit.
- then insert a delimiter based on the value of `i` (between every hex pairing).
- return the strand length prepended to the encoding.

```
static String hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    
public static String encode(String dna) {
    StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
    char[] n = dna.toCharArray();
    int len = dna.length();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        byte b = dnaToCode.get(n[i]);
        b <<= 2;
        if (i < len - 1) {
            b |= dnaToCode.get(n[i + 1]);
        }
        encoded.append(hexDigits.charAt(b));
        if (i % 4 == 2) {
            encoded.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return len + " " + encoded.toString();
}
```

**Decoding**

- to decode, just split on the white space.
- then grab the length as the first array element.
- for the rest, simply process two hex digits at a time, shifting and ANDing and using the other map to get the nucleotide for the encoding.
- the conditional checks for single digit hex tokens.
- then return the string which is adjusted for the actual length of the strand.

```
public static String decode(String code) {
    String[] s = code.split(" ");
    int len = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);

    StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(s[i], 16);
        if (s[i].length() > 1) {
            decoded.append(codeToDna.get(val >> 6));
            decoded.append(codeToDna.get((val >> 4) & 3));
        }
        decoded.append(codeToDna.get((val >> 2) & 3));
        decoded.append(codeToDna.get(val & 3));
    }
    return decoded.toString().substring(0,len);
}
```

**Testing**

Here is a method to test the code.

- it does 7 runs.
- generates random `dna` strand of length 1 to 10 inclusive
- then it encodes it.
- decoded the encoded string.
- and prints out the results for comparison.

```
public static void testit() {
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        int size = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        String generated =
                r.ints(size, 0, 4).mapToObj(codeToDna::get)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());
        String encoded = encode(generated);
        String decoded = decode(encoded);
        System.out.println("orig    = " + generated);
        System.out.println("encoded = " + encoded);
        System.out.println("decoded = " + decoded);
        System.out.println();
        
    }
}
```

prints something like

```
orig    = GGTAACTC
encoded = 8 AC 1D 
decoded = GGTAACTC

orig    = CACCTATTT
encoded = 9 45 CF C
decoded = CACCTATTT

orig    = TTCGGCACTA
encoded = 10 F6 91 C
decoded = TTCGGCACTA

orig    = CATACTAG
encoded = 8 4C 72 
decoded = CATACTAG

orig    = ACCCCG
encoded = 6 15 6
decoded = ACCCCG

orig    = GCATT
encoded = 5 93 C
decoded = GCATT

orig    = AGTCAGG
encoded = 7 2D 28 
decoded = AGTCAGG
```